# Transform doesnt work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

This is my code when the page starts up.

```
    var x = document.getElementById('mainNav').getElementsByTagName("LI");
    var delay = 0;
    var transition = 0.3;
        for (i=0; i<=x.length; i++){
            x[i].style.WebkitTransfrom = "translate3d(250px,0,0)";
            x[i].style.transition = "-WebkitTransform " +transition + "s " + delay +"s";
            //x[i].innerHTML = "changed";
            delay += 0.04;
        }
```

This is my code when I click the button.

```
var x = document.getElementById('mainNav').getElementsByTagName("LI");
            var delay = 0;
            var transition = 0;
                for (i=0; i<=x.length; i++){
                    x[i].style.WebkitTransform = "translate3d(0px,0,0)";
                    x[i].style.transition = "-WebkitTransform " +transition + "s " + delay +"s";
                    delay += 0.02;
                    transition += 0.04; // The higher the number, the slower of exponential decay
                    if (x[i].querySelectorAll('ul li').length>0){
                        x[i].style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.35)";
                        }
                    //x[i].innerHTML = "changed";
                }
```

When I click another button it goes through the same code when it starts. AKA closing it back.

It used to work, but now it doesnt. What happened was that I told these functions to call others to simplify code (Doesnt affect these in any way). I'm not sure why its not working.

Is there some syntax gone wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jQuery or something similar?

Comment: Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), and why not use jQuery for this?

Comment: @KasperSouren It's not that big of a deal. People don't *have* to use jQuery, especially when it's something small that isn't a problem in native JavaScript. OP: Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: @KasperSouren the only is x[i] is an undefined object, evaluating x[i].style

Comment: How about changing `i<=x.length` to `i<x.length`? It appears you trying to access the last element being outside of the array.

Answer (score 0):

It was an off by one error.

```
x.length-1;
```